# Give different styling layout to one customAdapter

Tags: android, custom-adapter

How to give a different styling to my customAdapter ? My custom adapter get it's layout view from it's getView method. What i want to do is to give different styling layout when the adapter is called from different activity. I tried to use interface but it shows error

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

this is my code inside my getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method :

```
if(convertView!=null){
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item1,parent,false);
}
```

After i implement interface :

inside **CustomAdapter** class

```
StylingView stylingView;
public interface StylingView{
    void styleView(View convertView,ViewGroup parent);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    stylingView.styleView(convertView,parent);
}
```

inside **FragmentSecondPage.class**

```
public class FragmentSecondPage extends ListFragment implements CustomAdapter.StylingView{
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        customAdapter.styleView = this;
    }
    @Override
    public void styleView(View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        if(convertView!=null){
             convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item1,parent,false);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this, or any other way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `getViewTypeCount()` & `getItemViewType(int position)` . Have a look at the below example.

```
public class MultipleItemsList extends ListActivity {

private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        mAdapter.addItem("item " + i);
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            mAdapter.addSeparatorItem("separator " + i);
        }
    }
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

    private ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private TreeSet mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet();

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
}
```

Here, `getItemViewType()' is your own logic. You can set a flag through constructor parameter of the adapter, to identify the activity and according to that, you can write logic to inflate corresponding layout.

Comment: but how do we do this, for different activity?

Comment: From Activity1, you call `mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(LAYOUT_TYPE1);` and from the Activity2, you call `mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(LAYOUT_TYPE2);`. <br/> Now, write logic inside the `getItemViewType()` to return 0/1 according to this String.

Comment: Now i get it, my error is on my if statement "convertView!=null" should be changed to "convertView==null"

Comment: Thanks also for your answer, I think i will use it in the future